# When I delete the code for the menu border in CSS, nothing changes

Tags: html, css, menu, border

When I delete the code for the menu border in CSS (not the header), nothing changes. I am trying to delete the border for the items in the menu as I want to input pictures which won't fit within the borders of each item. I delete #navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0; } and nothing changes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="videos.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vines.css" />
<title>Puppy Power</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="page">
<header></header>
        <div id="dog logo">
    </div>

<ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="vines.html">Vines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Failing Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Crazy Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Funny Dogs</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Photographs</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="hero"><h1><b>HERO</b></h1></div>



<div id="topvideo"><h1><b>TOP VIDEO</b></h1></div>

<div id="topphoto"><h1><b>TOP PHOTO</b></h1></div>

<div id="toparticles"><h1><b>TOP ARTICLE</b></h1></div>

<div id="content"><h1><b>CONTENT</b></h1></div>

<div id="footer"><h1><b>FOOTER</b></h1></div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>

#wrap {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#page {
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 900px;
    min-height: 1550px;
    max-height: 1600px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



#navigation {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 813px;
    height: 187px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px

}

#navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 159px;
    left: 80px;
}


.sub {
    display: none;
}

ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 79px;
}


#navigation li {

    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation   a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
}

#navigation   li:hover > a {
    background-color: #89cFF0;

}

#navigation li:hover > ul.sub{
    display: block

}


#hero {
    width: 813px;
    height: 408px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;

}

#topvideo {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 10px;



}

#topphoto {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}

#toparticles {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#content {
    width: 813px;
    height: 310px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {

    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I then delete the borders but it is still there....

```
#wrap {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#page {
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 900px;
    min-height: 1550px;
    max-height: 1600px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



#navigation {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 813px;
    height: 187px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px

}

#navigation li {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 159px;
    left: 80px;
}



#navigation , .sub {
    list-style-type: none;



}

.sub {
    display: none;
}

ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 79px;
}


#navigation li {

    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}



#navigation   li:hover > a {
    background-color: #89cFF0;

}

#navigation li:hover > ul.sub{
    display: block

}


#hero {
    width: 813px;
    height: 408px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;

}

#topvideo {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 10px;



}

#topphoto {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}

#toparticles {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#content {
    width: 813px;
    height: 310px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {

    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

`border: none;` should do it. Are you sure the CSS isn't cached? Try Ctrl + f5 to reload page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your separate CSS code differs from the CSS code beneath your HTML code ... for example `#navigation li` has an absolute positioning there.
But nevermind.

You're applying 2 different borders to each element in your menu.

First:

```
#navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 159px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

Second:

```
#navigation   a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
}
```

If you want to remove that border you have to remove it in both classes.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. I realised that in the first place. I have deleted border: 1px solid #89cFF0; from both classes of "li" and "a" and nothing changes.

Comment: Well then you haven't posted the whole CSS file (or you missed a part), because I copied your code and if I remove the mentioned parts the border are gone. Are you sure you work with the right file?

Comment: Edit posted. Thanks Tom, have a look.

Comment: I don't see any edit. You mean you edited your question?

Comment: There are no changes in your question ... at least I can't find any. And I tried that code again ... my suggested changes still working.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. For some reason my text editor "sublime" was only saving some certain parts of text for some really bizarre reason. I appreciate all your time and effort. Thanks.

Comment: Well no, I just copied it into notepad. The CSS is 100% linked up to the html as when I change other text in the same file, it changes the way the website looks. So that is really weird. Thanks anyway. Time to change text editor!

Comment: No, I meant are the borders gone now?